# Trying to get my form_alter function to be more specific

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I'm hiding access to a specific fieldset within the Support Ticketing System module add a ticket page. I use a `form_alter` preprocess function to find the page's form id as such:

```
drupal_set_message($form_id);
```

I discover the ID is:

```
support_ticket_node_form
```

... perfect so I do:

```
function MYTHEME_support_ticket_node_form_form_alter(&$form,$form_state,$form_id){
  $form['subscribe']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

... to hide that but the fieldset does not get hidden.

However, if I do a generic `form_alter`:

```
function MYTHEME_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['subscribe']['#access'] = FALSE;
}
```

... That works, the fieldset is now hidden on the page. The only thing I could think of that I am doing wrong is that it seems odd to have `form_form_alter` as part of the string but one is from the form ID and the other is part of the function so it should be working. Not sure what i am doing wrong. I'm guessing the generic `form_alter` that works for me could be dangerous as it lacks specificity and could cause issues down the road so I'd like to get this sorted out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hook for specific form ID's is [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7) (at the moment you're using something more like `hook_FORM_ID_form_alter()`). You should just need to change the name of the function to:

```
function MYTHEME_form_support_ticket_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // ...
}
```

and clear the caches.